# Casting List<Concrete> to List<InheritedInterface> without .ToList() copy action

Tags: c#, list, servicestack, ienumerable, covariance

I'm having some trouble with covariance/contravariance between List and IEnumerable, most likely I don't fully understand the concept. My class has to be a Concrete with Concrete properties so that they can serialize over the wire using ServiceStack (SS can't deserialize interfaces back properly, they end up null properties, I previously found a thread from mythz stating that they didn't want to support IoC and that your DTOs should always be just concretes. If this attitude has changed, or someone knows a quick workaround, great.)

A little about our architecture:

- We have EF Code First, which will have an entity like User, in a Schema project (DLL)
- We have an interface of `IUserModel` in an Interfaces project (DLL)
- We have a `UserModel` which has similar properties to User, but add more for convenient storage as both a Domain and DTO model, in a Models project (DLL).
- We have an actual ServiceStack DTO in a Service project like `CreateUser` which inherits the `UserModel` (to keep the amount of code in the Service project down, since it would literally be identical properties to the `UserModel`, but with the ServiceStack routes, and we can use the same `UserModel` for both `CreateUser` and `UpdateUser`, etc.)

Below is a snippet of what we basically have everywhere as our Domain models. There are over 200 objects that relate to tables in the database, but not the actual EF code first models so we can keep an abstraction layer between)

```
// Interface is in a lower level project that only has
// interfaces in it, no concretes
public interface IHaveNotesBaseModel
{
    List<INoteModel> Notes { get; set; }
}
// Concrete implements the interface explicitly so it can have
// the Concrete for ServiceStack serialization/deserialization
public class UserModel : IHaveNotesBaseModel
{
    public List<NoteModel> Notes { get; set; }
    List<INoteModel> IHaveNotesBaseModel.Notes
    {
        get { return Notes?.ToList<INoteModel>(); }
        set { Notes = value?.Cast<NoteModel>().ToList(); }
    }
}
```

Up until today, we thought this was working because in our Workflows layer, where we are trying to program to interfaces, it is adding stuff to the `User.Notes` list that is eventually mapped down but we found a scenario today where an `IUserModel` was passed into a function, a `NoteModel` was added to `Notes`, but if you where to later call the Concrete `Notes`, it doesn't have that object.

We've been researching for a way around this and found that `.ToList<INoteModel>()` is making a copy of the original and that appears to be the reason it's not working. We need a way to Cast from the concrete to the inherited Interface without making a copy of the list.

So the things we know we can't do because of ServiceStack are:

1. Change to `IEnumerable<T>`: ServiceStack won't deserialize the IEnumerable because it's an interface
2. Do a Cast `(List<INoteModel>)Notes`: Cast Exception
3. Do a Cast after `.Cast<T>`, `(List<INoteModel>)Notes.Cast<INoteModel>()`: Cast Exception

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 public class UserModel : IHaveNotesBaseModel
    {
        public List<NoteModel> Notes { get; set; }
        List<INoteModel> IHaveNotesBaseModel.Notes
        {
            get { return Notes.Cast<INoteModel>().ToList(); }
            set { Notes = value.Cast<NoteModel>().ToList(); }
        }
    }
```

full example :

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            UserModel um = new UserModel();

            um.Notes = new List<NoteModel>();
            um.Notes.Add(new NoteModel { MyProperty = 1 });
            um.Notes.Add(new NoteModel { MyProperty = 100 });
            um.Notes.Add(new NoteModel { MyProperty = 10 });
            um.Notes.Add(new NoteModel { MyProperty = 10000 });

            List<INoteModel> Notes = um.Notes.Cast<INoteModel>().ToList();
            ((IHaveNotesBaseModel)um).Notes = Notes;



        }


    }

    // Interface is in a lower level project that only has
    // interfaces in it, no concretes
    public interface IHaveNotesBaseModel
    {
        List<INoteModel> Notes { get; set; }
    }
    // Concrete implements the interface explicitly so it can have
    // the Concrete for ServiceStack serialization/deserialization
    public class UserModel : IHaveNotesBaseModel
    {
        public List<NoteModel> Notes { get; set; }
        List<INoteModel> IHaveNotesBaseModel.Notes
        {
            get { return Notes.Cast<INoteModel>().ToList(); }
            set { Notes = value.Cast<NoteModel>().ToList(); }
        }
    }
```